# SharePoint Online change in activity webpart creator of Site

Tags: csom, spo

Related question:
[Is "AllowUnsafeUpdates" available in SharePoint Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238352/is-allowunsafeupdates-available-in-sharepoint-online)

Since AllowUnsafeUpdates is not available via CSOM, i am trying to update this info in some manner.

I try this but no success

```
$adminUrl = "https://cutomer-admin.sharepoint.com"
$userName = "user@customer.com"
$SPOSite ="https://customer.sharepoint.com/sites/SPSite1/"
$DefaultEmailAddress = "AdmAccount@customer.com"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"

$creds = Get-Credential -Credential $userName
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $creds
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials -ArgumentList ($creds.Username, $creds.Password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSite)
$Ctx.Credentials = $SPOcredentials
$Web = $Ctx.Web
$SPODefaultEmailAddress = $web.EnsureUser($DefaultEmailAddress)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$Web.Author = $SPODefaultEmailAddress
$Web["Author"] = $SPODefaultEmailAddress
$Web.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you are updating the SharePoint online web property,and here I think after web object client context **load** and **executequery** is missing.

You can little modify your code :

```
$Web = $Ctx.Web
```

**$clientContext.Load(Web) $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()**

```
  $SPODefaultEmailAddress = $web.EnsureUser($DefaultEmailAddress) $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  $Web.Author = $SPODefaultEmailAddress

  $Web.Update() 
 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

I think we can do this one using PnP PowerShell command as well.

You can try the below command :

```
  Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://ktskumar.sharepoint.com/mywork -Credentials (Get-Credential)
Set-PnPWeb -Title "My Work"
```

Note - in the above web title is being updated, you can change it to author.

https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/07/update-sharepoint-web-title-using-pnp-powershell/

**Update** :

- **Set-PnPWeb** does not have **author** property.
- In SharePoint server side dll, **author**  property has both **get** and **set** but client side dll has only **get** property. So, we cannot change this property value in SharePoint online.

Comment: i think the pnp cmdlet doesn't have author property. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpweb?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: I have tried load the web context but the problem is still that "author" is a read-only property

Comment: Ohh, I server side author property has get set and client side dll doesn't have set property